# How can I store large amounts of unorganized, related data and organize it as I receive it?

Tags: parsing, entity-framework-6, storage, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm writing a program for a client. The data they send us is essentially information from a relational database that got flattened, resulting in utterly gigantic comma-delimited text files that consist of extremely redundant information with only a few fields changing per line.

I am reading this into a typed dataset and essentially organizing the data I'm getting into the third normal form, which drastically cuts down on the sheer amount of redundancy. From there, I convert the data in the dataset to XML and send it off to another program to create forms and statements.

However, I'm wondering if there's a better way to go about this. It might not be as bad as I think it is, but I can't shake the feeling that there's a better, faster way to do this. The important thing is that the data is organized and easily understood, and that it is constraint-checked and validated before I convert it to XML.

Since none of the data needs to persist (in fact, it shouldn't), an actual RMDB didn't seem worth it if I was just going to end up clearing it after every use.

The program also needs to run in a myriad of environments; my workstation is Windows 7 64-bit, the testing server is Windows XP 32-bit, and the production server is Windows 7 64-bit or 32-bit depending on which server it's going on.

Comment: Define 'Bottleneck' - while a dataset might be heavy compared to say an array, it sounds like you do need the data in some kind of structure so you can remove duplicated fields etc, and the dataset has the advantage of named fields, making it easier to debug.
" The important thing is that the data is organized and easily understood, and that it is constraint-checked and validated before I convert it to XML." - you've pretty much talked yourself into the dataset right there ;-) .

Comment: @peterG Bottleneck might not have been the right word. But I am still wondering if there's a better or faster way to do this. It doesn't seem like there is at first glance; the closest equivalent I could find would be to run sqlite using an in-memory connection.

Comment: So much depends on the circumstances of the app and the data - you say text file - is it CSV or similar? Personally I'm more confident with SQL than LINQ, so if it were me, (I'm embarrassed to mention;-) ) that would also influence my decision - also just how practical is an in-memory approach - does this have to run on client machines that might be running XP for ex, or do you know it'll be running on a 64-bit 32GB box? Also how important is performance as opposed to say, maintainability? A DB solution where you can check intermediate tables etc might be easier to work with, even if slower...

Comment: @peterG I added some more detail to the body of the question, but it's a CSV file with 52 fields. Of that 52, less than half change frequently.

I'm very comfortable with both Linq and Sql. 

Performance is key; a ton of information (hundreds of thousands of records) is being read in at a time.

Comment: IMHO then I would start off with SQL Express - it's designed to work its way through those kinds of data volumes, and will adapt itself to the different platforms you're running; it's scalable to the bigger versions if necessary; and in SSMS you have a tool for easily examining intermediate results etc., and importing .csv is straightforward. Going back to your original q, my opinion fwiw is that this is a reasonable approach; I don't think you're missing anything.

Comment: @peterG if you make this an answer I'll upvote it and accept it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO then I would start off with SQL Express - it's designed to work its way through those kinds of data volumes, and will adapt itself to the different platforms you're running; it's scalable to the bigger versions if necessary; and in SSMS you have a tool for easily examining intermediate results etc., and importing .csv is straightforward. And it's free.
For all the above reasons, I would give SQL Express a try and evaluate its real-world performance.
Going back to your original question, my opinion fwiw is that this is a reasonable approach; I don't think you're missing anything.

Comment: Newer versions of SQL Express have the LocalDB option, which looks like the perfect solution. Thanks for the help!